# Trigger a key event on Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following Tinymce config setup:

```
    //set up a new editor function    
    setup : function(ed) { 
    //peform this action every time a key is pressed
    ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) { 
    //setting our max character limit
    tinymax = 10;
    //grabbing the length of the curent editors content
    content = ed.getContent();
    
       var content_text = $(content).text();
       var tinylen = content_text.length;
    
    //if the user has exceeded the max, trigger enter and create a new paragraph
    if (tinylen>tinymax){
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13; // Enter keyCode
$(".content").trigger(e);           
}
}
```

What doesn't work is the trigger event. What I'm doing wrong here?
By the way (".content") is the name of the text area, I also tried (ed) and it didn't work.

Comment: do you just want to break the line, or is there a handler that is triggered when the enter key is triggered?

Comment: @AlexCheuk Just break the line, although in tinymce, when you hit enter it creates a new paragraph, thats what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to try and answer. The way that you are triggering the event is correct. I have a example here that confirms it works. http://jsfiddle.net/3WsJE/

When triggering the "return" key with jQuery, the key actually does not get entered into the value of the textarea.

I dont know if this is what you want, but if you were planning to trigger the Enter key to simply insert a line break, you can try this solution.

```
$(".content").val( $(".content").val()+'\n');
```

Comment: It works in regular text areas, but when i try it on Tinymce, it doesn't, something like your second answer seems to be the way, instead of triggering key events. Thanks.

Comment: I accept your answer because you're the only one who responded, and because it lead me to the right answer.